# Evaluate $\int_{C}\frac{|z|\mathit{e}^{z}}{z^{2}}dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Evaluate $\int_{C}\frac{|z|\mathit{e}^{z}}{z^{2}}dz$, where $C$ is the circumference of the circle of radius 2 around the origin.

I wanted to use the Cauchy integral formula, but is $|z|$ analytic on the circle? The answer is $4\pi i$.

Any advice on which theorem I must use? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $|z|$ is not analytic on the circle, but it is constant ($z=2$) on the circle centered at the origin and of radius $2$!

So

$$\int_{C}\frac{|z|\mathit{e}^{z}}{z^{2}}\,dz=2\int_{C}\frac{\mathit{e}^{z}}{z^{2}}\,dz=2\cdot 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{z=0} \frac{\mathit{e}^{z}}{z^{2}}=4\pi i.$$